# for duplicate question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Please consider this change for duplicate questions.

Instead of closing/flagging as duplicate, have a link provided which redirects to a question(s) that already exists. Sometimes people do not understand the actual question and will close it as a duplicate, when it perhaps is not really a duplicate.

If you provide this type of facility, the user who asked the question will get a chance to select from the marked duplicates and its answers, which are suggested by the other users, then they can choose to link that question to its original and have it directly closed.

If it is not a match, he can explain why, and what is different about it

In short:

people have to suggest which is similar question available

if user get answer from that suggested link. he/she join his/her question with that question. and then automatically question will close.

Comment: Sorry but I have no slight idea what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: people have to suggest which is similar question available

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that I am fairly sure was meant here. Please let me know, @jubinPatel if I got it right.

Comment: I have no clue what is being asked here.

Comment: if user get answer from that suggested link he/she join his/her question with it. and then automatically question will close

Comment: You want the question owner to be able to close as a duplicate with a single vote, is that it?

Comment: yes you get that

Comment: Look how this guy's reputation suffers a huge hit for raising this issue. I have to say I'm really sick of asking questions on this site. People answer questions for free in their spare time, what is the issue with letting a few things slide, for the sake of what the OP stated that many posts are misinterpreted and reinterpreted wrongly. But why should I suggest anything? Stack Overflow is run by know-it-alls with 17k reputation who all think exactly alike. @Shadow Wizard, you have no idea what is being said here - why not read it again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We already do that with automatic "possible duplicate" comments, and users with sufficient reputation can vote to close their own questions in agreement.

If a question is closed wrongly it'll be reopened in due time.

Comment: that is word matching, i am telling about perfect similar question.

Comment: if anyone know similar question like that then provide its link like an answer,and if you provide,user get point on true connect with  question

Comment: I just said we already do that.